# Prove $2\geq x(x+1)$ for all real numbers in range $-2$ to $1$ inclusive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers

Prove that if $x$ is a real number such that $x(x + 1)>2$, then $x <−2$ or $x > 1$.

I think this is easy to prove by contrapositive, and thus,

if $x\ge -2$ and $x\le{1}$, then $x(x+1)\le 2$.

Notice that $ x(x+1)=x^2+x$ and that $x^2\ge{0}$ for all $x$ in the real numbers.

Since $-2\le{x}\le{1}$ implies $x^2\le 4$.

Now I am stuck. How can I show that this is always less than $2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $$-2\le x \le 1$$
we want to prove that
$$x(x+1)\le 2$$
or
$$(x+\frac 12)^2\le 2+\frac 14=\frac 94$$

so
$$-2\le x \le 1 \;\;\implies -\frac 32 \le x+\frac 12\le \frac 32$$

$$\implies 0\le (x+\frac 12)^2\le (\frac 32)^2$$
Done.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a hint:**

the product $(x-1)(x+2)\gt0$ if both factors are negative or both factors are positive.

Comment: Could you explain why you are multiplying these

Comment: I factored $x(x+1)-2$

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+x 
=(x+1/2)^2-1/4
$
so 
$2-(x^2+x)
=9/4-(x+1/2)^2
=(3/2-(x+1/2))(3/2+(x+1/2))
=(1-x)(2+x)
$

so
$2 \ge  x^2+x$
if and only if
$(1-x)(2+x) \ge 0$
if and only if
$1-x \ge 0$
and $ 2+x \ge 0$
or
$1-x \le 0$
and $ 2+x \le 0$
if and only if
$x \le 1$
and $x \ge -2$
or
$x \ge 1$
and
$x \le -2$.

The second can't hold
so the condition is
$x \le 1$
and $x \ge -2$.